# Extending JavaScript for carousel/image cycle function

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to modify the following snippet of JavaScript that cycles through 2 images:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var swap = 0;
        var homeimg = new Array(1);
        homeimg[0] = "http://media.com/i/ct/11-hp-main?w=2350&h=1056&qlt=50";
        homeimg[1] = "http://media.com/i/ct/11-hp-main-mens?w=2350&h=1056&qlt=50";
        setInterval(function() {
          swap = (swap ? 0 : 1);
          $(".homepage-mainimage img").attr("src",homeimg[swap]);
        },4000);
    </script>
```

Please may I ask why after I have tried to extend this script to accommodate 8 images why it is not functioning? I am struggling to understand why the script has broken.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var swap = 0;
        var homeimg = new Array(7);
        homeimg[0] = "http://media.com/i/ct/15-hp-main-1?w=2350&h=1056&qlt=50";
        homeimg[1] = "http://media.com/i/ct/15-hp-main-2?w=2350&h=1056&qlt=50";
        homeimg[2] = "http://media.com/i/ct/15-hp-main-3?w=2350&h=1056&qlt=50";
        homeimg[3] = "http://media.com/i/ct/15-hp-main-4?w=2350&h=1056&qlt=50";
        homeimg[4] = "http://media.com/i/ct/15-hp-main-5?w=2350&h=1056&qlt=50";
        homeimg[5] = "http://media.com/i/ct/15-hp-main-6?w=2350&h=1056&qlt=50";
        homeimg[6] = "http://media.com/i/ct/15-hp-main-7?w=2350&h=1056&qlt=50";
        homeimg[7] = "http://media.com/i/ct/15-hp-main-8?w=2350&h=1056&qlt=50";
        setInterval(function() {
          swap = (swap ? 0 : 8);
          $(".homepage-mainimage img").attr("src",homeimg[swap]);
        },1500);
    </script>
```

Comment: You're initializing an array with too few elements. `Array(7)` creates an array with 7 elements, but you have 8 images. Additionally, you should set `swap = (swap ? 0 : 7);`

Comment: @Solomon thats not really the problem

Answer (score 0):

`swap = (swap ? 0 : 8);`

Will mean that it just swaps between the first and the last image. If you want to cycle through them all, try something like

`swap = (swap >= 8 ? 0 : ++swap)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are expecting `swap = (swap ? 0 : 8);` to act as change it between 0 and 8, but that line does not do that. If swap is different than 0, it will go to 0 and if it was 0, it will go to 8. Basically, you are only swapping first and last images. What you want is :

```
swap = (swap + 1) % (homeimg.length + 1);
```

Comment: better solution than mine, easier if the array changes length in future, and since it's all arithmetic it avoids missed branch predictions for performance too. Nice.

Comment: @KarlReid always good to avoid constants where possible, but yours might be easier to understand